# jQuery selecting text from within span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic list created and need to be able to select data held within two span tags when clicked. My code so far is:

```
var app_data="<li class='auto' 
    data-short='"+this['dish_short']+"' 
    data-desc='"+this['dish_desc']+"' 
    data-dish_id='"+this['dish_id']+"'>
         <span class='m_name'>"+this['dish_name']+"</span> - £<span 
         class='m_price'>"+this['dish_price']+"</span>
</li>";
```

Please note that the line breaks within the code are to make it more readable rather than it being all on one line.

What I am trying to do is select the text from each of the span classes although so far with the code below it is selecting all the text eg. the dish name AND the dish price.

Code:

```
 $('li').click(function(){
    //alert($('li', this).data('short'));
    var m_name=$(this, 'span .m_name').text();
    console.log(m_name);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **dynamic list created** use `.on` to assing click or other events.

**Example**

```
$(document).on('click','li',function(){
   //code here
});
```

Comment: Possibly the event is bound *after* the elements are added to the DOM.

Comment: @VisioN and for that possibility i give OP solution about do not repeat function call everytime dom added later...

Answer (score 3):

The context part goes as the second argument (i.e. `$(selector, context)`), as well as `m_name` class is set to `<span>` elements, so there shouldn't be any space in the selector:

```
var m_name = $("span.m_name", this).text();
```